# CONSTRAINT_ERROR when using LCM function

Tags: ada

I am trying to write a user defined task scheduling policy for Cheddar in ada language. but when i write the following code:

```
mul:=1.0;

for i in tasks_range loop
    if tasks.ready(i)=true then
        mul:=lcm(tasks.capacity(i),mul);
    end if;
end loop;
```

It gives an error: Exception raised :CONSTRAINT_ERROR:expressions.adb:1876 access check failed

I tried defining mul as integer and it failed there too.

Please help.

Comment: Sorry, but there are at least 1870 other lines that might have something to do with this. You’re going to have to cut it down (quite a lot) to produce a [mcve].

Comment: See also [*Gem #142 : Exception-ally*](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-142-exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of info that we need in order to really give you any meaningful help.
As a guess, given the exception is `Constraint_Error`, I'd look at the range of `tasks_range` compared to `tasks.ready` & `tasks.capacity`. — Given that this doesn't look like idiomatic Ada code, I'm guessing you're either (a) trying to transcribe the method/algorithm from some other language, or (b) you are unfamiliar with Ada's `task` system.